# bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile and bpy.context issue

Tags: python, import

I am trying to run a script that reload a scene and import some fbx.
The python script works wonderfully with blender in Background mode, but if I try to run the script from the blender text editor. I am getting some errors related to the context.
The error I am getting is this
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'selected_objects'
I am assuming is something related to context.areas?
Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks!
Here is a snippet of the code

```
import bpy
import os

file_path = bpy.data.filepath
print("================AREAS=====================")
print(bpy.context.screen)
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    print(area.type)


bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=bpy.data.filepath)

bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=file_path)
print("================AREAS=====================")
print(bpy.context.screen)
if bpy.context.screen:
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        print(area.type)

dir = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)
def import_fbx():
    fbx_path = os.path.join(dir, "test.fbx")
    bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=fbx_path)
    
import_fbx()
```

Comment: how are you executing the script with blender in background? and which OS are you using? btw i don't see any usage of selected_objects in your script. are u using it somewhere or is it internally accessed?

Comment: are you using `bpy` from pypi? https://pypi.org/project/bpy/ i think, that isn't "full" bpy, i think its intended for using the math parts without the blender parts, for things like testing algebra